# roscd problems!

Tags: ros, roscd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been having trouble with this command for a while. It started when I was studying "[beginner_tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials)". But now, when I'm at [tf2](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials), it's annoying.
So, this is usually what I write in my Terminal and these are the answers I receive:

```
*as@as-Inspiron-1545:~$ cd tutorial_ws
as@as-Inspiron-1545:~/tutorial_ws$ source devel/setup.bash
as@as-Inspiron-1545:~/tutorial_ws$ roscd src
roscd: No such package/stack 'src'
as@as-Inspiron-1545:~/tutorial_ws$ source ~tutorial_ws/devel/setup.bash
bash: ~tutorial_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
as@as-Inspiron-1545:~/tutorial_ws$ source ~/tutorial_ws/devel/setup.bash
as@as-Inspiron-1545:~/tutorial_ws$ roscd src
roscd: No such package/stack 'src'
as@as-Inspiron-1545:~/tutorial_ws$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/home/as/tutorial_ws/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share*
```

Mention that in ~/.bashrc I have these lines:

```
*source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash #source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
source ~/tutorial_ws/devel/setup.bash*
```

Any help to clarify would be grateful

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279546/roscd-problems!/) by [xtrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/32780/xtrix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2018-01-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xtrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/32780/xtrix/) on 2018-01-11**:
@mig Can you tell me how did you frame my cod?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-11**:\

1. Enter your code
2. Highlight it
3. Click the *preformatted text* (`101010`) button or press `Ctrl+k`

**Comment by [xtrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/32780/xtrix/) on 2018-01-12**:
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`roscd <pkg>` brings you to a package. `src` is just the source folder of the workspace, and no package. I'm pretty positive that no tutorial tells you to do a `roscd src`, for that matter.

`roscd tf2` e.g. brings you to the location of the `tf2` package, e.g.

FYI, with catkin, the latest sourced `Setup.bash` wins. There is no Need to have multiple in the `~/.bashrc`.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xtrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/32780/xtrix/) on 2018-01-11**:
Thank you. I re-read about workspaces and packages. They have not been clear enough, but it seems to be a beginning.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-12**:
If this answer solved your problem then please click the checkmark to mark the answer as correct.